# A language that is not even context-sensitive?

Tags: computer-science

Is there a language *actually in use* that can't be recognized by a linear bounded automaton?  I only know of ones that don't have a practical use, like "the set of pairs of equivalent regular expressions with exponentiation" (Wikipedia).  Or would any such language be too slow to recognize to be useful?

Comment: In use by whom? For what? Would "English" count?

Comment: Does something PSPACE-complete count as useful? Because those certainly can't.

Comment: Automated proof checkers are computer programs that recognize the language of all valid proofs in some system. I don't think this language can be recognized by a linear bounded automaton, but I don't actually know.

Answer (score 3):

The set of true statements in [Presburger Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) is not context sensitive (as it has been shown that it is not $\text{NPSPACE}(n)$ decideable).

As for being in actual use, don't know.

Got from: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/5064/is-there-an-example-of-a-non-context-sensitive-language

Answer (score 0):

I think any problem with [non-elementary complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NONELEMENTARY) should do, e.g. "correctly typed programs" for some complex type theories might be just an example you look for ;-)